# How do I properly mirror this across to the other half of the circle?

Tags: mirror, mirror-modifier

I'm decently new to Blender. I want to mirror these balls across to the other half of the circle. Here is what it looks like before mirror:[image] And here's what it looks like after.

[image]
That is as close as I can get it. What am I doing wrong here? I'm stumped honestly.

Comment: hello could you please share your file (only the useful objects)? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The `Mirror Object` field is what you want. it is used to describe the location and orientation of the mirror separately from the main object.
You typically use empties with it.

I would suggest creating a new Empty, parenting it to the center stem, aligning it with the stem, and placing it exactly between the 2 hemispheres.

You would then select it in the `Mirror Object` field of your mirror modifier